# Python Exception ImportError - Attempted Relative Import with No Know Parent Package

Tags: python, exception

I am currently getting to grips with O-O in Python. As such, I am trying to logically separate my classes into different directories. I am using Python 3.9.

I have the following structure (an _*init*_.py file has been created in every directory):

- Base Folder
- _*init*_.py

  - Models
  - _*init*_.py

    - Product

      - _*init*_.py
      - ProductModel.py
  - Controllers
  - _*init*_.py

    - Product

      - _*init*_.py
      - ProductController.py

However, within ProductController.cs I am struggling to reference ProductModel.cs:

```
from ...models.product.ProductModel import ProductModel
```

Which gives me the following error:

```
Exception has occurred: ImportError
attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Comment: is there a `__init__.py` file in each of the folder? [python packaging](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/)

Comment: @Mr.Hobo Excellent spot, I had included the \__init__.py files but I hadn't documented them in my question (corrected).

Comment: I am unable to replicate your issue :(